# How was the political landscape of Tibet during the era of fragmentation?

Tags: medieval-china, tibet

When reading about the end of the Tibetan empire, information about the political situation of the area is scarce (most authors focus a lot on the religion).

Basically, who was *de facto* or *de jure* in charge of its regions? The buddhist monastic schools?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Maybe I wasnt't too clear, sorry for that. I want to know the political landscape of Tibet at the time. I know there was no single power looming over it, but which were the most influent imperial houses and religious schools?

Comment: Regional warlords were in charge of their little slices of Tibet. It's not called Era of *Fragmentation* for no reason.

Comment: @Semaphore Yeah, but several times we hear, for example, about the Sakya overlordship over many kingdoms founded by descendents of the imperial house after the Mongol conquest. I presume the Sakya were viewed as important, both to the mongols and to the other tibetan houses, and maybe this was also the case during the age of fragmentation.

Comment: Sakya was founded in 1073, amost two hundred years before the capitulation of Tibet to the mongols. With the exception of the Nyingma-Pa (which was apolitical and descentralized), the Sakya-Pa,  the Karma-Pa and the Kadam-Pa were involved in politics in 12th century Tibet. Guge and Burang remained as kingdoms well into the 13th century aswell.
I find it really hard to find information about the political situation in Tibet because most autheors focus on the religious side of the school leaders.
I know Tibet was sparsely populated, but there's literally no info to be found in the usual sources.

Comment: I'm not asking about a central authority, sorry if my question sounded like that. I was asking about regional powers and the political landscape at the time.

Comment: I wanted to ask this exact same question haha. Has there been any clarification since the last posting? I am currently working on mapping every polity in Asia in 1200. I've got the kingdoms already listed but that still leaves a huge chuck of Tibet unfilled.

Comment: @nomadicsquirrel I was writing a bit about it for a project, for which I would need an accurate representation of East Asia and adjacencies in 1130. Basically, I was able to get a detailed description of everything, including governors, revolts and usurpers, but Tibet.

Comment: When Nima-gon died around 930AD, Mnah-ris (Ngaris), the Western Tibetan Empire, was divided among his three sons: Pelgyi-gon, the eldest and thus the suzerain over the others, got Manyul (Upper Ladakh), Tashi-gon got Gugé and Purang, and Detsu-gon got Zanskar, Lahul, and Spiti.

Comment: Later, Lhachen Utpala (1080-1110), grandson of Pelgyi-gon and the king of Ladakh, vassalized Purig, Purang and Kullu (Lahul-Spiti). Lhachen Nagloka succeeded him (1110-1140) and built the citadel-palaces of Vanala and Khalatse.

Comment: @nomadicsquirrel here's the [source](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=R4VuovXa5YUC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Osung+tibet&source=bl&ots=IcCSczQY9U&sig=Rl40bqmZQGP038AVIBdsVTf-N5E&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=4zWgVOfQAsGLNsG7gLgK&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Osung%20tibet&f=false) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Made my comments into a provisory and partial answer.

In western Tibet it seems the kingdoms of Guge, Purang, Mar-yul, Yar tse and Zanskar were still around by the 11th century. **Couldn't find anything from eastern tibet, unfortunately.**

When Nima-gon died around 930AD, **Mnah-ris** (Ngaris), the Western Tibetan Empire, was divided among his three sons: Pelgyi-gon, the eldest and thus the suzerain over the others, got **Manyul** (Upper Ladakh), Tashi-gon got **Gugé** and **Purang**, and Detsu-gon got **Zanskar**, **Lahul**, and **Spiti**.

Later, Lhachen Utpala (1080-1110), grandson of Pelgyi-gon and the king of **Ladakh, vassalized Purig, Purang and Kullu** (Lahul-Spiti).

You can get most of that info if you follow the timeline in [Buddhist Western Himalaya: A politico-religious history](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=R4VuovXa5YUC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Osung%20tibet&source=bl&ots=IcCSczQY9U&sig=Rl40bqmZQGP038AVIBdsVTf-N5E&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=4zWgVOfQAsGLNsG7gLgK&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Osung%20tibet&f=false)